# Error when installing Geonode: cannot find django-geonode-mapstore-client>=2.1.0

Tags: django, geonode

I am very new to programming. I am trying to install GeoNode on an AWS Windows EC2 image, according [to this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ochieng.grace/geonode-installation-on-windows-7302686176b3) (which is super, by the way!)

When I get to the `pip install -e geonode` stage, the error in my Command Line is this:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-geonode-mapstore-client>=2.1.0 (from geonode) ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-geonode-mapstore-client>=2.1.0`

When I look at how to install django-geonode-mapstore-client, the only webpage I can find is this: https://pypi.org/project/django-geonode-mapstore-client/ which works, but it installs django-geonode-mapstore-client 2.0.9. It seems that 2.1.0 has been [bumped in a week ago](https://mirror.openquake.org/git/GeoNode/geonode/commit/d25d84c4e5460ba280935684535820c442925485) and I'm not sure what to do at this point. When I run pip install -e geonode I get the same error message after installing client 2.0.9 and no other part of the paver setup process works.

I am wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same issue, or has advice on how to proceed? Is there a way to force it to install 2.1.0?

Comment: Any tip on how you overcame this issue?